# Adding struct timespec to class (and seeminly no other type) causes EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I am trying to determine the dt that my engine is running in using `sys/time.h`

I thought I might do this by storing the struct timespec as a private member of my Engine class however that causes an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in a completely unrelated section of the code.

Oddly enough I can add private int, long, and void* arguments in its place without causing a crash.

Here are the relevant parts. A lot has been cut out

```
class Engine {
private:
    static Engine* instance;

    Engine();

    struct timespec last;

public:
    static Engine* shared() {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = new Engine();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    Engine(const Engine&) = delete;

    // EntityManager
    EntityManager entityManager;
    bool setCount(int num);

};
```

Yes this is a heap allocated semaphore. It is that way for a very important reason.

Just adding last causes an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in a method of EntityManager inside of its initialization code it mallocs a large chunk of memory and then allocates each object calling its defalut constructor like so:

```
for (int i = activeCount; i < realCount; i++) {
        char* entityStart = pool + sizeof(Entity) * i;

        new(entityStart) Entity(i+1);
}
```

And the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS shows up as being in the first line of the default Entity class that I made. The first line simply sets a property of the Entity.

This is very confusing to me, especially since types other than struct timespec can be added without issue. So I am wondering what might cause this. Do you have any ideas? Is it possible that this is a compiler issue of some sort?

Comment: we'd need a [mcve] to help, the issue is likely in the code you haven't posted

Comment: Just sounds like UB to me. Problem is somewhere else. Compiler problem is **very** unlikely.

Comment: I have tried creating a minimal example but if I remove anything it no longer crashes. I am trying to cut it down as we speak but the end product is still going to be a lot of files of code.

Comment: If you would like I can send specific people a copy of the project as well.

Comment: @J.Doe In my experience if the problem goes away when you remove seemingly unrelated code, then the problem is in that unrelated code. No guarantees of course!

Comment: In the mean time of me trying to figure this out it would be great to hear some general theories as to what causes this sort of thing.

Comment: out of bounds memory accesses or stack overflows, OSX doesn't seem to reliably detect stack overflows and just crashes with `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` instead. Check for incorrect array/vector indexes, large stack allocations or infinite recursions. The message usually also contains the address that your program couldn't access which should be a clue

Comment: Alright so the hunt continues. I put my engine code into a format I can also test in terminal. Valgrind reported a conditional jump based on uninitialized data and I caught an uninitialized int. However I am still having issues. I am wondering if it is a bad idea to mix malloc and posix_memalign in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I ended up resolving this and it may have been more than acouple things. If you are having this issue check for the following:

- Are reconstructors being called when you dont expect them to
- Are you initializing all fields that need it such as ints
- Are you mixing malloc with posix_memalign (I stopped doing this but it could be completely fine i'm not sure)

Good luck!